# Secure order preserving hash function

Tags: hash, order-preserving

Is there a construction of an order preserving hash function that keeps the preimage property of a crypto hash function? By order preserving hash function (OPHF) i mean for $x<y$ then $OPHF(x) < OPHF(y)$

Comment: That can't really be a hash anymore. Your condition can only be satisfied by order preserving encryption. It implies having different results for each input, and not just that collisions are hard to find.

Comment: Read the CryptoDB paper. I think what they use is the best thing we have, but it obviously has significant weaknesses inherent in order preserving encryption.

Comment: Why can't be a hash? I was thinking of a hash as i don't care about decryption. I do only care for preimage resistance. In CryptoDB paper they don't say how they apply order preserving encryption. This paper "An Ideal-Security Protocol for Order-Preserving Encoding" claims to achieve the best security we can gain for order preserving encryption by mutable ciphertexts.That is ciphertexts periodically are deleted in the db. Still in the paper the way OPE as a crypto primitive is constructed is not not described in technical detailsv.Is it just multiple encryptions(AES) until order is preserved?

Comment: I mean for the same reason order preserving encryption is not considered as secure encryption OPHF wouldn't considered as secure hash...

Comment: Your requirement trivially allows a binary search to recover the the message in a chosen plaintext scenario. It's also easy to prove that the only way to satisfy the condition is order preserving encryption. So I have no clue what you even mean by an oder preserving hash.

Comment: I want a  representation of plaintexts such that: 1) order of plaintexts is preserved into their scrambed representation (digest if hash ciphertext if encryption), 2)I want this to be one-way with no inversion. These requirements seem to me to resemble into a hash and not an encryption scheme. Am i wrong on that?

Comment: Your requirements are simply a contradiction. Order preservation allows binary search which allows trivial and efficient inversion of any unkeyed function.

Comment: But the same approach can be applied to reserve the encryption scheme, with a binary search, given many e encryptions of ciphertexts or i am wrong...?Would a keyed order preserving hash function sounds feasible?

Comment: $OPHF(x):x\mapsto x||\operatorname{SHA-256}(x)$ is order-preserving, and second-preimage resistant. It is not first-preimage resistant, though.

Comment: @fgrieu i am wondering if this is the only way to preserve the order. Just by prepending the value before a crypto hash...

Comment: It is impossible to build a public (key-less) hash function that is order-preserving and first-preimage resistant. Problem is, it is possible to quickly find the preimage by dichotomy.

Comment: @fgrieu Is it possible to fix a keyed hash function then that is order-preserving and first-preimage resistant?

Comment: @fgrieu: $\:$ SHA is completely irrelevant for your construction. $\;\;\;$

Comment: In Boldyreva et al.'s [second paper on OPE](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~aboldyre/papers/operev.pdf) they describe a scheme that uses as an order-preserving hash function something called a monotone minimal perfect hash. I don't know all the details, but look at the top of page 11 for the description.

Comment: To the OP: It's also possible to construct an order-preserving compression algorithm for strings: [1](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=765545&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=566392357&CFTOKEN=47961008) [2](http://www.cs.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Informatik/AG-Boettcher/Lehre/WS_09_10/pro-sem-ws09/Dictionary-based_Order-preserving_String_Compression_for_Main_Memory_Column_Stores.pdf)

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304549263_Application_Layer_Encryption_for_Cloud has an OP hash construction. Of course, with the same limitations that any OP function has, that of some minimal leakage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with a hash function like you ask for is that, if you hash an $n$-bit string and give the hash to someone else, they can recover the string using $n$ hash calculations with a binary search.

For a simple example, let's say the $n=8$, your string is $01011001$ in binary, and its hash is $Y = H(01011001)$.

1. To recover the string from the hash, I start by calculating $X_1 = H(10000000)$ and comparing it with $Y$.  Since $10000000 > 01011001$, and since $H$ is order-preserving, $X_1 > Y$ and I therefore now know that the first bit of your string is $0$.
2. Next, I'll calculate $X_2 = H(01000000)$ and again compare it with $Y$.  Since $01000000 < 01011001$, this time $X_2 < Y$, and thus I now know that the first two bits of your string are $01$.
3. Using this knowledge, the next hash I'll calculate will be $X_3 = H(01100000)$.  Since $01100000 > 01011001$, now $X_3 > Y$, and thus I know that the first three bits of your string are $010$.
4. The next hash I'll calculate will be $X_4 = H(01010000)$, which I'll compare with $Y$ to find the fourth bit of your string, and so on, until I've recovered every bit of your string.

This flaw is inherent in the idea of order-preserving hashing: if I can obtain the hash of any valid string, then I can always carry out such a search.  In fact, even if I *can't* get the actual hashes, but can only ask you for the result of the comparison between $H(s)$ and $Y$ for some input string $s$, I can *still* recover your original string without even seeing its hash value!

Basically, if you ever played the ["guess what number I'm thinking of?"](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-guess-the-mystery-number-in-guessing-games/) game as a child, this is exactly the same situation.  You have a secret string, and I get to guess a string and see if it's less than or greater than your secret.  As in the game, with the right guessing strategy I won't need too many guesses to find the right answer.

Comment: what if the hash function is not publicly available and it's keyed

Comment: @curious: If I can choose a string and ask you for its hash, then the attacks still works. Even if I can only ask whether the hash of my string is less than the hash of your string, that's still enough information for this attack.

Comment: Then through that attack i can break any Order preserving "encryption" scheme once i have access to an oracle that is encrypting for me... [OPE](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~franklin/ecs228/2013/boldyreva_etal_2009.pdf)

Comment: "if the hash function is not publicly available and it's keyed" then you have order-preserving encryption.

Comment: @curious: Yes. As the paper you linked to notes at the end of section 1, order-preserving encryption is useless if the attacker has access to an encryption oracle.

Comment: @curious: $\:$ That is just recovering a plaintext, not breaking the OPE. $\;\;\;$

Comment: if breaking means not semantically secure that implies indistinguishability which if you can recover plaintext obviously doesn't hold then it's broken...(?)

Comment: @curious: Full semantic security with OPE is impossible anyway, and, technically, being able to efficiently recover plaintexts using an encryption oracle doesn't break the alternative security definition suggested by Boldyreva _et al._ It still makes the system rather useless in situations where such oracle access is possible.

Comment: Right because they can't prove that in semantic security game INT-CPA then they look at left or right in which extra restrictions are made, they stipulate that even LoR game is not enough and then they describe the ideal OPE and they compare it with a real one.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Semantic security as traditionally understood is impossible, but OPE can achieve something almost as good if the ciphertexts are exponentially larger than the plaintexts.

Comment: @pg1989: Interesting. Can you describe this "something almost as good" in more detail? (In particular, I don't suppose it helps to avoid the binary search attack, since that's a generic plaintext recovery attack against _any_ OPE scheme that allows encryption oracle access.)

Comment: It's IND-OCPA, the security goal presented in [Boldyreva's first OPE paper](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~aboldyre/papers/bclo.pdf). Bottom of page 2 and bottom of page 6.

Comment: To everyone in this thread: A new paper on OPE was released a couple months ago. [It's on ePrint.](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/409.pdf) Discusses security notions of OPE schemes in detail.

Comment: @pg1989 if you can sum up the new results of the paper it would be great

Comment: I can't do it in a comment, it's 40 pages long - a particularly dense 40 pages at that. One of their main goals is to reduce the necessary leakage of OPE schemes so that OPE can be achieved in the model described by Boldyreva with fewer than 1/2 the bits leaked. They do accomplish this. Their final scheme can leak much fewer than 1/2 the bits of the plaintext. However, they also show the number of bits leaked can never be zero. They do this using min-entropy in an argument I don't fully understand yet. They also define a couple new OPE security notions that their scheme provably meets.