# Order preserving hashes

Tags: hash, one-way-function, order-preserving

Are there hash functions that dynamically take integers a and b, and output h(a) and h(b) such that if a>b we have h(a) > h(b)?

Comment: This would be very weak, subject to a binary search. Your question has already been answered elsewhere. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/secure-order-preserving-hash-function

Comment: I have voted to close this duplicate question